# Fast algorithm to find the n1 th smallest number to n2 th smallest number in an array

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, columnsorting

I have an array, I attempt to find the **n1** th smallest number until the **n2** th smallest number in the array and store them in another array of size **n2-n1+1**. Here **n2**>**n1** and both are realtively small compared to the size of the array (for example, the array size is 10000, **n1=5**, **n2=20**).

I can sort this array first, and then retrieve the **n1** th number, **n1+1** th number until the **n2** th number from the sorted array. But since **n1** and **n2** are usually relatively small compared to the size of the array, it is not necessary to sort the array completely. The algorithm should be able to stop in middle once reaches **n2** I think.

I wonder if there is any algorithm, maybe a modified version of certian sorting algorithm that is specifacally good (by good I mean fast) at this problem. You can either use Python code or pseudo code as an illustration, thanks!

Comment: What you're looking for is some usage of [selection algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm)

Comment: So maybe using [`np.partition`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.partition.html)? Something about this question looks like a rehashed assignment.

Comment: I think quickselect would be O(N) independent of n1 and n2.  That will be optimal.

Comment: Is O(N) for finding one element? Then the complexity would be roughly O(N2N) for this problem? Do you think this can be beat @Arun Kumar's answer?@strubbly

Answer (score 1):

Since, the N1 and N2 are really small compared to size of array  letus  say N.
We can have an implementation in O(N2 * LogN) using min heap data structures.

**Steps**

1. Construct a min heap. Complexity of this operation will be O(N)
2. Loop for a range of 0 to N2:
        Get the root element and call heapify. Ignore first N1 elements and return rest of the elements. Complexity of this step is O(1)+O(logN)
   Hence, overall we have O(N2 * logN)

Comment: Can I ensure that you are just saying using [heapsort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heapsort) and stop at N2?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of sorting, if your array size is not very big you can use simple lookup table (kind of sorting here). Firstly iterate over array and just store lookup[array[i]]=true;
and then just iterate over lookup and do something like:

```
for(...){
if(lookup[j]){
    ith++; 
    if(ith>=n1 && ith<=n2)
       ADD(j);
}}
```

That would be O(n), if you have a window n1<=n2 rather nothing faster than O(n) exist

Comment: This question was only tagged with `python`, and this definitely isn't python syntax.

Comment: @roganjosh the OP specifically stated: "You can either use Python code or pseudo code as an illustration, thanks!"

Comment: This is just a simple pseudocode, i think solution matters more than language itself

Comment: What's a "lookup table"?  Why is it sorted?

Comment: for example: bool lookup[SIZE];   that means you can check if [0][1][2][3][4]... element is set (setting it as lookup[element]=true)   at the end you have a lookup table that looks like [0][1][0][0][0][1]...   which means that element 1 and 5 is first and second lowest element..

Comment: Ahh I see.  So not going to work if the array is of Python long ints.

Answer (score 0):

Use [selection sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort). It's O(*n*²) if you sort the entire array, but O(*mn*) if you only sort the smallest *m* items in the array.

Answer (score 0):

If **n2** (and therefore **n1**) are both small, then you can find the **n2** smallest elements and ignore the first **n1** ones.  These approaches are described by Arun Kumar and user448810 and will be efficient as long as **n1** remains small.

However, you may be describing a situation in which **n1** (and therefore **n2**) can grow (perhaps even linearly with the overall list length) and it is only their difference **n2-n1** which remains small.  In this case you need a selection algorithm such as quickselect which will remain O(N) in this case.